Health Connect RemoteException: Request rejected. Rate limited request quota has been exceeded
I'm using the Health Connect sdk to retrieve distance records. This is the code that i have:
suspend fun readDistanceInputs(start: Instant, end: Instant): List<DistanceRecord> {
    var pageToken: String? = null
    val records = mutableListOf<DistanceRecord>()

    do {
        val request = ReadRecordsRequest(
            recordType = DistanceRecord::class,
            timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(start, end),
            pageToken = pageToken
        )
        val response = healthConnectClient.readRecords(request)
        pageToken = response.pageToken
        records.addAll(response.records)
    } while(pageToken != null)

    return records
}

This works perfectly for almost all the users but some users recives this exception:

RemoteException: Request rejected. Rate limited request quota has been
exceeded. Please wait until quota has replenished before making
further requests.

It is strange because most of the users get this exception from the first time they use the app, and most of the users do not have any problem.
Why is this happing?
Thanks

Did you see this issue?

@tomerpacific yes, thanks! But the thing is: someone that install for the first time the app, receive this exception in the first request to the sdk.

I am also seeing the same issue with Health connect, if any one can provide any help that will be so great!
